# Filter controller condition by value in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller

I have the following code in one of my controllers (in a Rails 3.1 application) which works well:

```
def index
    #@calls = Call.all
    @calls = Call.where(:destination => '12345678').limit(25)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @calls }
    end
end
```

I'm trying to work out the best way of proceeding from here, basically each user has their own destination code (in this case it's 12345678).

Is it possible for the users to have a value in a model which can be passed into the controller?

An example

```
def index
    #@calls = Call.all
    @calls = Call.where(:destination => '<% @user.destination %>').limit(25)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @calls }
    end
end
```

I realise that the above code wouldn't work but what would be a workaround to achieve the same thing?

Update with a little more information:

I have two models, one is calls and the other is users.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
@calls = Call.where(:destination => @user.destination_id).limit(25)'
```

Where :destination is part of the Calls model and destination_id is part of the users model. Each user has a different destination_id value.

**Routes**

```
Outofhours::Application.routes.draw do
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
resources :users
resources :sessions

resources :calls
root :to => 'dashboards#index'
resources :dashboards
end
```

**user model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :company, :destination_id, :password, :password_confirmation

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :company
  validates_uniqueness_of :destination_id

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

**call model**

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the destination to the controller in the `params` array. This way you could access it in the controller like this

```
def index     
  #@calls = Call.all
  @calls = Call.where(:destination => current_user.destination_id).limit(25)

  respond_to do |format|       
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @calls }     
  end
end
```

Comment: Is that possible if it's from a different model, so this controller (above) is the calls model and it's filtering based on a User model? @calls = Call.where(:destination => params[@user:destination_id]).limit(25)

Comment: Should be. Assuming that `@user` is available to the view you are coming from, you would just pass the `@user.destination` in the `params` array by doing something like this `link_to('link text', call_path(:destination_id => @user.destination))`

Comment: I can't get this working. I have the following in my index method in the Calls controller '@calls = Call.where(@user.destination_id => @user.destination_id).limit(25)'

Comment: Not quite. In your Calls controller you want `@calls = Call.where(:destination => params[:destination]).limit(25)`. Whatever link you are clicking that is leading you to this page needs to pass the `destination` value in the params using the `link_to` method in my comment above.

Comment: I'm confused. I'm not clicking any links. I'm looking at the calls#index method which has a table full of calls. I'm trying to filter that list of calls in my Calls controller depending on which user is looking at it. Each user has an 'destination_id' (their phone number) which matches the destination table in the Calls model. Does that make sense, I'm finding it difficult explaining it.

Comment: Apparently we were talking about it from two different directions. Please post your `routes.rb` and your Users and Calls models. That'll help us see what's going on and how to help.

Comment: I've added just about everything :) Nothing is in the call model though, should it be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6679/discussion-between-paul-simpson-and-dannymcc)

Comment: Sorry I missed you in chat, your updated answer worked perfectly. Thanks!